# Android App crashing on startup with fatal exception

Tags: java, android

I am getting the following code errors in LogCat...any fix? What is info.androidhive.androidsplashscreentimer.Splashscreen?I wanted to display the splash screen before the main activity. Can anyone also explain to me what error message to look at in order to find out the issue that log cat has generated?

```
06-09 11:43:18.800: E/AndroidRuntime(824): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-09 11:43:18.800: E/AndroidRuntime(824): Process: com.example.apocalypse, PID: 824
06-09 11:43:18.800: E/AndroidRuntime(824): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.apocalypse/info.androidhive.androidsplashscreentimer.SplashScreen}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "info.androidhive.androidsplashscreentimer.SplashScreen" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.apocalypse-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.apocalypse-2, /system/lib]]
06-09 11:43:18.800: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
06-09 11:43:18.800: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-09 11:43:18.800: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-09 11:43:18.800: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-09 11:43:18.800: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-09 11:43:18.800: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-09 11:43:18.800: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-09 11:43:18.800: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 11:43:18.800: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-09 11:43:18.800: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-09 11:43:18.800: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-09 11:43:18.800: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-09 11:43:18.800: E/AndroidRuntime(824): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "info.androidhive.androidsplashscreentimer.SplashScreen" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.apocalypse-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.apocalypse-2, /system/lib]]
06-09 11:43:18.800: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
06-09 11:43:18.800: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
06-09 11:43:18.800: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
06-09 11:43:18.800: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
06-09 11:43:18.800: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
06-09 11:43:18.800: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  ... 11 more
06-09 11:43:24.160: I/Process(824): Sending signal. PID: 824 SIG: 9
06-09 11:43:45.990: D/AndroidRuntime(929): Shutting down VM
06-09 11:43:45.990: W/dalvikvm(929): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a79ba8)
06-09 11:43:46.000: E/AndroidRuntime(929): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-09 11:43:46.000: E/AndroidRuntime(929): Process: com.example.apocalypse, PID: 929
06-09 11:43:46.000: E/AndroidRuntime(929): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.apocalypse/info.androidhive.androidsplashscreentimer.SplashScreen}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "info.androidhive.androidsplashscreentimer.SplashScreen" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.apocalypse-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.apocalypse-2, /system/lib]]
06-09 11:43:46.000: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
06-09 11:43:46.000: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-09 11:43:46.000: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-09 11:43:46.000: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at  android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-09 11:43:46.000: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-09 11:43:46.000: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-09 11:43:46.000: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-09 11:43:46.000: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 11:43:46.000: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-09 11:43:46.000: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-09 11:43:46.000: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-09 11:43:46.000: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-09 11:43:46.000: E/AndroidRuntime(929): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "info.androidhive.androidsplashscreentimer.SplashScreen" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.apocalypse-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.apocalypse-2, /system/lib]]
06-09 11:43:46.000: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
06-09 11:43:46.000: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
06-09 11:43:46.000: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
06-09 11:43:46.000: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
06-09 11:43:46.000: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
06-09 11:43:46.000: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  ... 11 more
```

My manifest is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.apocalypse"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <!-- Splash screen -->
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.androidsplashscreentimer.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Main activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.androidsplashscreentimer.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: It looks like there may be something wrong with your manifest - can you post that?

Comment: Your packeges does not match. You `have com.example.apocalypse` and your activity `info.androidhive.androidsplashscreentimer`

Answer (score 2):

You package `com.example.apocalypse` does not match the one from your Activity (`info.androidhive.androidsplashscreentimer`), either you put in your Activity element `name=".SplashScreen"` or `name="com.example.apocalypse.SplashScreen"`, but not `info.androidhive.androidsplashscreentimer.SplashScreen`. Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.apocalypse"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <!-- Splash screen -->
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Main activity -->
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
```